# How to know how many times the network is turned on/off in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, networking

Right now I can know how many times my app is sending request to the remote server. I'm wondering is it possible that the app turn on/off the network connection several times during these requests. For example, say the app sends 10 requests in total. If it sends these 10 requests intensively (e.g. in the first 2s), is it possible that the network is first turned on then turned off when it detects there is no more request to send? In another situation, if 10 requests is sent uniformly within first 60s (1 request every 10s), is it possible the network is turned on to send the first request, then turned off, then turned on to send the second request, then turned off? Is there any way I can know how many times my network is turned on/off in one session?

Comment: Are you talking about the use turning the network on or off or are you asking about your apps use of the network. In the latter case you can use the energy monitor in the debugger and the enegery profiler in Instruments

Comment: @Paulw11 Is it possible to know it programmatically?